# Is there a way to disable hidden colums when search in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this data from the database in a foreach loop. When I click the quantity plus button, the price gets multiplied by the quantity and then I get the total. Then after getting the total, I would want to sum all the totals in the loop. And that works just fine. But when I search a data to add quantity, I get the total but the total doesn’t sum to the other totals

[image]

Im using datatables for the search.  the jquery only recogise the first data records... so when u search, the new record is not included that is why it is not working when u search. Please help me fix this

```
// Calculating Sub total for all Items
function totalAmount(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.total').each(function(i, e){
        var amount = $(this).val() - 0;
        total += amount;
    });
    
    console.log(total)
    $('.sub_total').val(total);
    // $('.balance').val(total);
    $('.total_charge').val(total);
}
                
// Incrementing Quantity Value
$('.plus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
            
    let qtyID = $(this).attr('data-input');
    let priceID = $(this).attr('data-price');
    let sub_total = $(this).attr('data-total');
    var my_sub = $(this).attr('data-sub_total');
    var my_sub_total = 0;
    let newValue = parseInt($('#'+qtyID).val());
    if(!isNaN(newValue) >= 1) {
        $('#'+qtyID).val(newValue + 1);
        var qty = $('#'+qtyID).val();
        var price = parseInt($('#'+priceID).val())
        var total = priceID * qty;
        // alert(total)
        $('#'+sub_total).each(function(i, e){
            $(this).val(total);
        });
        // $('#'+sub_total).val(total);  
        var tot = parseInt($('#'+sub_total).val());
        // Calculating for the sub total
        totalAmount();
    } else {
        $('#'+qtyID).val(0);
    }
});

// datatable();
var table = $('#table_wf').DataTable();
```

Comment: It looks like you're calculating the total from the DOM `$('.total').each` - when using datatables you should always use the data from datatables, not from the DOM.  If you had paging (and enough rows to page) then your total would only be for the "current page" as the other pages are not in the DOM.

Comment: **I'm using datatables for the search. the jquery only recogises*" - you've not included how you're using "jquery for the search" - it may be that you should be using datatables for the search, not jquery, so that it searches across all pages.   Your provided code seems related to calculating totals, not searching, so it's hard to tell *which* is your issue (totals or searching) - if searching, please include the code you use to search.